# Consecutive writes to pipe without blocking and closing reader

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

What I whant today is reading/writing from named pipe without blocking,
and close pipe on both sides without killing a process.
I'm strugling with process closed after firset wright to pipe.
I have some code for you to help me with my troubles.

```
    mkfifo _gnupg_pipe_command

    gpg --homedir ./ --batch --verbose \
        --pinentry-mode loopback \
        --gen-key _gnupg_pipe_command &

    cat > $_gnupg_pipe_command <<EOF
%echo Generating a basic OpenPGP key
Key-Type: RSA
Key-Length: 4096
Key-Usage: sign
Subkey-Type: RSA
Subkey-Length: 4096
Name-Real: $_gnupg_name
EOF

    if [ -v _gnupg_comment ]; then
        cat > _gnupg_pipe_command <<EOF
Name-Comment: _gnupg_comment
EOF
    fi

    cat > _gnupg_pipe_command <<EOF
Name-Email: _gnupg_email@_gnupg_universe
Expire-Date: 1y
Passphrase: _gnupg_passphrase_key
# Do a commit here, so that we can later print "done" :-)
%commit
%echo done
EOF
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/085 might be helpful.

Comment: Why do you have `$` before the pipe filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the commands in a list or subshell, and redirect the whole thing to the pipe.

```
{ 
command1
command2
command3
} > _gnupg_pipe_command
```

The pipe will be opened just once at the beginning, and closed when all the commands complete.

If it's a one-liner you need appropriate spaces and `;`, since `{` and `}` are not self-delimiting syntax, they're keywords.

```
{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; } > _gnupg_pipe_command
```

Obviously the script in the question can't be a one-liner because of the here-docs.

Comment: please note in case someone wants to do this as an one-liner, spaces and the last semicolon are important `{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }`